# why is my view still presented in landscape?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

my view is controlled by a navigation controller, so I set the supported orientations in to the navigation controller to explicitly portrait & portraitUpSideDown and this works, however if the previous view was in landscape when the view was called upon, it will present itself in landscape and stay in landscape until the device is rotated.. How do I prevent this?

Here is my code:

```
class EditProfileViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.delegate = self
}

func navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(navigationController: UINavigationController) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown]
}
```

I thought the previous line would lock the view into portrait permanently, how do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your orientation back to portrait before dismissing it:

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")

dismiss(animated: true) { _ in
    print("dismissed in Portrait mode")
}
```

Comment: exactly where should I write this code to impact the navigationController?

Comment: before you dismiss the viewController which may be in Landscape mode

Comment: but the thing is, I want to effect the orientation while the view is here, not before its dismissed.. can you provide an answer that sets the orientation to portrait if the device is in landscape when its presented..

Comment: You can add this code to viewDidLoad but believe me it is much better to rotate the view back to portrait before dismissing it. You can also create a custom navigation controller and  override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool { return false }

Comment: but, i don't want the user to interact with the view in landscape at all, thats why. but I'll try it right now

Comment: They won't even see it

Comment: haha, you must not understand, if the view is presented in landscape, i want it to automatically switch to portrait, not wait till the view gets dismissed to switch to portrait.. does that make sense?

Comment: and I just implemented it , yes it works when the view is being dismissed.

Comment: but i need it to get rotated in portrait AS SOON as the view is presented, thats IF its presented in landscape

Comment: Just check orientation in viewDidLoad and if landScape force it to portrait