# Force a single view to be a different orientation to set device orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, rotation, orientation

I have seen this question posted in many forms, but the answers either don't work for me, or are in obj-C. In my project settings i set the device orientation for all the views to Portrait. How do i force only a single view to appear landscape (with rotation disabled)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/32707930/2303865

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to set orientation to either landscape left, right, or just landscape

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft; // can also do .Landscape or .LandscapeRight
}
```

Comment: first i get an error saying that this method does not override any method from its superclass. If i delete the override from the function declaration, i get the error:
"Method 'supportedInterfaceOrientations()' with Objective-C selector 'supportedInterfaceOrientations' conflicts with method 'supportedInterfaceOrientations()' from superclass 'UIViewController' with the same Objective-C selector"

Comment: Can you show me the whole class? If you start typing `override func supportedInt...` in your view controller does the autocomplete show anything?

Comment: It offers me the following function:
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    }

Comment: then do this `override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft;
    }`

Comment: It returns an error as there the function is missing a return statement

Comment: sorry i forgot the return keyword, should be good now! by the way part of programming is figuring out solutions yourself ;)

Comment: When your previous sultion never worked i actually tried the solution you gave just gave me. I also read that the supportedInterfaceOrientations function is only called if the shouldAutoRotate function returns true, so i added that in as well. Even with this i get the error "Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application". Thank you for your help on this question, it is much appreciated

Comment: I didn't mention it before but I am presenting the view as a popover. Do you think this might be influencing the behaviour?