# Force Landscape when orientation is locked

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a video app. When a user rotates the device to landscape, the video takes over all of the screen and the UI changes.

Is there a way to 'force' landscape layout when the device is in portrait? For example, if the user has orientation lock we want to add a button to enter the landscape mode. The YouTube app has a button that does this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32707641/2303865

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is my view still presented in landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707641/why-is-my-view-still-presented-in-landscape)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can force it using this 2 lines of code, in your `viewDidAppear`

```
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So simple, I had spent a long time on Google trying to find that answer.